# Using Javascript to validate response in the text box

Tags: javascript, form-validation, web-services

I am new to Magento. I have the following requirements.

A page has a text box where the customer enters an id. Once the id is entered, I need to check whether this id is available in the OMS using a OMS webservice call. And if the id is valid, I need to enable the submit button in the page. If the id is invalid I need to disable the submit button.
Could someone give me some direction on this.

Thanks

Update:
I tried to do this using the following code,
Javascript: The function will called on click of the submit button

```
                   submit.onclick = function()
                    {
                        $.ajax
                        ({
                            url: "<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/OnepageController/checkid')?>",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: {id: '2345'},
                            dataType: json,
                            success: function(data) {
                                status = data;
                            }
                        });
                    if (status=='invalid')
                        {
                            alert('id function was not hit');

                            return false; // cancel submission
                        }
                    else if (status=='valid')
                        {
                        alert('id function was hit');
                        return true;
                        }
                    }
```

Php: Magento Controller

```
public function checkidAction()
{
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    if ($id=='1234')
    {
    $status = "valid";
    }
    else
    {
        $status ="invalid";
    }

    echo json_encode($status);
}
```

Could you please tell me if something is wrong here. I am not able to get the status information back to the ajax call. Thanks

Comment: Is your controller return result? could you add the code for you input field and the path to the phtml files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use magento form validation class, then create a  new "remote validation", take a look at [Magento form field AJAX validation](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-frontend/magento-form-field-ajax-validation/)

In your phtml file add

```
<script>

Validation.add('validate-customer-id', 'Please enter a valid id. For example xxx-yy-mmm.', function(v) {     

    // do your OMS webservice call in your controller 
    // you could use post this need to be secure
    var url = '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/OnepageController/checkid', array('id' => 2345))?>' + encodeURIComponent(v);

    var result = false;

    new Ajax.Request(url, {
        method: 'get',
        asynchronous: false,
        onSuccess: function(transport) {
            var obj = response = eval('(' + transport.responseText + ')');

            if (obj.is_available === 0) {
                result = false;
            } else {
                result = true; /* return true or false */    
            }
        }
    })

    return result;
});

</script>
```

Update your input with

```
<input ... class=".. validate-customer-id" />
```

In your controller

```
public function checkidAction()
{
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    if ($id=='1234')
    {
       $status = array('is_available' => 0);
    }
    else
    {
       $status = array('is_available' => 1);
    }

    echo json_encode($status);
}
```

Also see 
 [Magento prototype custom validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15027613/magento-prototype-custom-validation)

Comment: Thank you for the response. But I am still not clear how to go about this.

Currently my javascript code for the text field that needs to be validated is as follow,
Order.onclick = function(){
                n2 = $('name2').value;
                num2 = $('number2').value;
                if (num2=='1234')
                {
                    alert('Please check your id');
                    $('number2').focus();
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                return true; // allow submit
                }};

Comment: So when I enter 1234 in the text box and click submit button it shows an alert box that says 'Please check your id' and does not take me to the next page which is what I want.

Now, instead of checking if num2 is equal to 1234, I want to call a webservice passing in '1234' which will return a response saying whether the id is valid or not and only if the response says the id is valid i want the submit button to take me to the next page. Else an invalid id alert should be displayed and the pressing submit button should not take me  to the next page. 

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at my update